# Which one is correct "eth" or "est" with Thou in a verb?

Tags: grammar

In a hundred prismatic manifestations, thou makest/ maketh the goblet whirl.Nurturing the mirror of an astounded gaze, it is I!

Comment: "Thou makest faults graces that to thee resort." --- Shakespeare

Comment: I'm going to leave this site.Andrew Leach, TimLymington

Comment: I don't need to learn English

Answer (score 2):

makest

(archaic) second-person singular simple present form of make.

Thou makest us a byword among the heathen, a shaking of the head among the people. - Psalms 44:14

maketh

(archaic) third-person singular simple present indicative form of make

The answer is 'makest'.

Source: Wiktionary